# Is there a connection between the Eye of God from Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood and the Rinnegan from Naruto?

Tags: naruto, fullmetal-alchemist-series

After watching FMA again, I couldn't help but notice the similarities:

- The same ripple-like pattern.
- Both related to godly powers.
- Both related to balance (Yin-Yang/All-One)
- Both related to life and death.

[image: Rinnegan] [image: Eye of God]

Is there a mythological or conceptual connection between the two? Is one based on the other?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Although I can't find any reliable source, it seems that both are based on Saṃsāra :

> The repeating cycle of birth, life, death and rebirth (reincarnation) within Hinduism, Buddhism, Bön, Jainism, and Yoga.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsara)

This represents both the Six Paths of Pain (also Rinne is the Japanese Name for Samsāra) and the "one is all, all is one"-thing in FMA (as seen in episode 12 of the 2009-anime).

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, both are different series in different scenarios. Anything related is because of the different meanings of our cultures that come from ancient myths.